# Is there a way to grant a user access to only all non system views of database?

Tags: sql-server, security

In SQL Server, I have a user in a particular database and I've been asked to grant them access to all of the non-system views of the database only. I believe this can be done by editing securables of type view and granting select on each one, but there are many, many views. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is **no** syntax such as

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL::Views TO SomeUser
```

You can `GRANT SELECT` permissions on individual [objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx), [schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx) or the entire [database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) but not filtered by object type to only include Views. For this sort of adhoc task I'd probably create a new role called `ViewReader`, add the user to that role then in SSMS run

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + 
          QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + 
      ' TO ViewReader;'
FROM sys.views
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
```

to generate a script to run to `GRANT` the required permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely graceful answer. The script is a little over my head so I'll do some reading before trying to implement. Thanks again.

Comment: @lush - The script just gives you some commands to review, copy, paste and run. You could do something more elaborate to concatenate the result and `EXEC` but I wouldn't bother for a one off task.

Comment: I understand now, this is a perfect solution for this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I took another approach in my case. This is what I did:

1. Create a login and map it to a database.
2. Go to a database an create a schema called Public_View for example. The owner of this schema must be the same owner of the tables that the views are gonna refer.
3. Grant the new user access to the new schema.
4. Create as many views as you want in the new schema and the new user will have access to them.

The good thing is that the new user will not have access to the tables, he won't even be able to see the tables.

I hope it helps.

Comment: +1 To me the good thing about this solution over mine is that there is no need to assign permissions explicitly when new views are created.